# What are the solutions to $\partial_{x_i x_j} F(x) = 0$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $F\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^d, \mathbb{R})$. I'm looking for solutions to $\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x_1 \partial x_2}(x) = 0$ or $\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x_1 \partial x_1}(x) = 0$. My guess is, that every solution can be written with $h,g \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^{d-1}, \mathbb{R})$ as

$$F(x) = g(x_2,x_3, x_4,\dots,x_d) + h(x_1,x_3,x_4,\dots,x_d)$$

or

$$F(x) = x_1 g(x_2,x_3, x_4,\dots,x_d)+h(x_2,x_3, x_4,\dots,x_d)$$

I was not able to proof this or find a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is correct. For example, suppose that the $x_1$-derivative of $\frac{\partial  F}{ \partial x_2}$ is identically zero. It follows that this function does not depend on $x_1$. So it can be written as $\phi(x_2,\dots,x_n)$. Integrate this with respect to $x_2$, obtaining a function $\Phi$ such that $\frac{\partial  \Phi}{ \partial x_2} = \phi $.

Next, observe that $(F-\phi)$ does not depend on $x_2$, and conclude with 
$$F = \Phi(x_2,\dots,x_n)+\Psi(x_1,x_3,\dots,x_n)$$
as desired.